# C# Save duplicate of Active document, but include track changes

Tags: c#, ms-office

I'm working on Word 2010 plugin and I want to copy active document with track changes (http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/word-help/turn-track-changes-on-or-off-HA010370561.aspx) to XML format and later to send it somewhere else.

This is my code:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document documentNew = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document();
object missing = Type.Missing;

document.Range(ref missing, ref missing).Copy();
documentNew.Range(ref missing, ref missing).PasteAndFormat(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdRecoveryType.wdFormatOriginalFormatting);

Object xmlFormat = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatXML;

documentNew.SaveAs2(file, xmlFormat);
```

This works, but does not include track changes in duplicate document. Anybody have idea how to also include changes?

Answer (score 0):

How about saving document to the new document in XML first, then opening up the new document and make whatever changes are required?  I've tested this approach and it preserves the tracked changed without having to do anything special.

Copy and pasting into a new document is not going to preserve the original tracked changes.

So the code would be:

```
public static void SaveAsXMLAndDoSomethingElse() {
    String fn = @"C:\Users\zbook\Desktop\Track test.docx";
    String fn_xml = @"C:\Users\zbook\Desktop\Track test3.xml";
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
    Documents docs = app.Documents;
    Document doc = docs.Open(fn, ReadOnly:true);
    //bool b = doc.TrackFormatting; // for some reason this line bombs
    doc.SaveAs2(fn_xml, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatXML);
    doc.Close(false);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(doc);

    // now open up fn_xml ... and do whatever

    app.Quit(false);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(docs);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(app);
}
```